# Unique Fields with the ability to be a reference to multiple records

Tags: 7, entities

I wonder to know is it possible to have an unique field (let consider a text filed), when we input a data into it firstly it check the table if it doesn't exist add a record, if it find a record refer to it?

i.e.: I have a field in my content type to store telephone number whenever I want to add a new node, after entering the data into the telephone field if the number was stored in my database instead of creating a new record in the table I just reference to the number

My aim is to have a contact list of some users that submit a form but I don't want duplication (just unique phone number and name)

Comment: did you used hierarchical select module??

Comment: Thanks Adi for your reply. I used it before but how the module can deal with my problem??

Comment: install this module and define term field in your content type when everytime you create a record already enter record display in select list

Comment: but it just show those phone numbers that I've created before, I'm not able to  add a new record automatically.

Comment: simple disable option to add new value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would envision this as

- Create a rule that post a node each time the form from anonymous user is submitted.
- Create a condition before creating a node - the condition will loop through all entered node telephone numbers if they found that the user has already entered the data don't do anything other wise post the node with phone, name and email information.

Comment: Thanks Shabir but I don't want to be stopped. I need to reference to the record

Comment: You can add a validater function in node form alter and once the validation of uniqueness failed load the node by phone number and populate the values, I am not sure what you mean by reference. Do you want to update the values in that case?

Comment: no I just want to use the number same as select list.

Comment: Okay, what happens if the number already exists? I am sorry but I am not getting your words

Comment: may be you could look at this https://www.drupal.org/project/field_reference module

Comment: according to your requirement use entity_reference or term reference

Comment: Thanks Guys. Shabir maybe my conception is wrong. what would you do if you want to have a contact list (name, telephone number and contact information ) for the users who submited a form in your site (they can submit multiple time but one time we need their information)?

Comment: I would just stop them from doing so :) what you are trying to achieve is not understandable

Comment: ;)) to make it clear I'm creating a site that people (anonymous) can insert some products information into it (i.e. their car: model- picture-color) and I show them in my site. they might have multiple car so an individual can submit multiple times. I also want to keep their contact information (name- telephone-email) . I hope I can explain it clearly

Comment: Okay, so when they add any information about products you extract email, phone and insert it as  a node?

Comment: yes exactly, I just want to keep their contact information

Comment: I think you need to fire a rule everytime the form is submitted and then in action you should see if the form has been submitted by a user whom information is already in the system don't add any node, otherwise add the node

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33169/discussion-between-mohammad-yousefi-and-shabir-a).